# Magento slideshow images are not getting updated

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento and trying Magento 1.7
I have installed a theme and trying to change the images of the theme. I copied the new images in the right path and renamed those to the old image name. I was expecting the new images will show up,  but it is not working.
I made sure the new images are also png files and of same size like the existing one.
What I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I was not chaging the png file permission.
I changed it starts working